# Send message to main room on pidgin in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, pidgin

i need to create a python script to send a message with specifics alerts to main room of pidgin chat in order to all people connected can see the alert, message and so on.

I have a sript working, but only sends the message to a specific person, but i need to send the message to main room.

the script is this:

```
import dbus
session_bus = dbus.SessionBus()
purple_obj = session_bus.get_object("im.pidgin.purple.PurpleService","/im/pidgin/purple/PurpleObject")
purple_int = dbus.Interface(purple_obj, "im.pidgin.purple.PurpleInterface")

user = "here i put the people, but i need the main room"

my_account_id = purple_int.PurpleAccountsGetAllActive()[0]
conv = purple_int.PurpleConversationNew(1, my_account_id, user)
conv_im = purple_int.PurpleConvIm(conv)
purple_int.PurpleConvImSend(conv_im, "the message.......")
```

any tip to send to all people in the main room?
thanks